# Locating DTEDs from one layer that intersect polygon in another layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I'm new to the GIS world, and using ArcGIS 10, so please forgive me if this is a simple question.  I have DTED files (level 2) that I have placed into a mosaic dataset, and I'm trying to determine which DTEDs intersect a polygon in another layer.  I'm using python, and used the SelectLayerByLocation method, but am having trouble getting the results from it.

I can't use the CopyFeatures method (which is what's in all the examples) because it's probably returning a mosaic layer instead of feature.  I also tried the Copy method, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Here's that part of my code:

```
   arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management('CreateMosaicDataset', 'mosaic_lyr')
   arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("mosaic_lyr", "INTERSECT", buffershape)
   # If features matched criterias write them to a new feature class
   arcpy.Copy_management("mosaic_lyr", "DTEDs_for_Shape")
```

---

My solution was:

```
  # Create a Mosaic Layer from the mosaic dataset
    arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management('CreateMosaicDataset', 'mosaic_lyr')
    # Select DTEDs intersecting the polygon
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("mosaic_lyr/Footprint", "INTERSECT", buffershape)
    # write selected features to a new feature class
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("mosaic_lyr/Footprint", "DTEDs_for_Shape")
```

Comment: please be more specific about the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select the dted that is intersected by a polygon.
You probably need to utilze the footprint in the mosaic dataset.

Comment: When I used ArcMap, I used the footprint to find the intersecting dteds.  But, how do I specify the footprint in the python script?  The SelectLayerByLocation method currently runs without errors, but I don't know what to use to 'get' the results.  Do you know what I need to use to get those results?  When I try CopyFeatures, it says "the value is not a Feature (or Raster Catalog) Layer".  When I try Copy, it says "value is not a Data Element".  I'm stumped :-)

Comment: Brad - Thanks so much for suggestion - it led me to my solution.  I should've realized it myself, since I used the footprint when I did the selection manually in ArcMap!    Here's my solution:                                              # Create a Mosaic Layer from the mosaic dataset
arcpy.MakeMosaicLayer_management('MosaicDataset','mosaic_lyr')
# Select DTEDs intersecting the polygon
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("mosaic_lyr/Footprint", "INTERSECT", buffershape)
# write selected features to a new feature class
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("mosaic_lyr/Footprint", "DTEDs_for_Shape")